# In R, indicate whether another column has more than one unique value per ID

Tags: r, dplyr

**Background**

Here's a dataset, `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b"),                  
                product_code = c("B78","X31","C12","C12"),                  
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It looks like this:

[image]

**The Problem and Desired Output**

I'm trying to make an indicator column `multiple_products` that's marked `1` for `ID`s which have more than one unique `product_code` and `0` for those that don't. Here's what I'm looking for:

[image: what_i_want]

My attempts haven't worked yet, though.

**What I've Tried**

Here's my current code:

```
d <- d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(multiple_products = if_else(length(unique(d$product_code)) > 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

And this is the result:

[image: what_i_have]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `d$` should be taken out as this will extract the whole column by removing the group attributes.  Also, there is `n_distinct`.  In addition, there is no need for `ifelse` or `if_else` as logical values (`TRUE/FALSE`) can be directly coerced to `1/0` as these are storage values by either using `as.integer` or `+`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(multiple_products = +(n_distinct(product_code) > 1)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  ID    product_code multiple_products
  <chr> <chr>                    <int>
1 a     B78                          1
2 a     X31                          1
3 b     C12                          0
4 b     C12                          0
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing -- seems like a dumb oversight on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

solution with `data.table`;

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d)

d[,multiple_products:=rleid(product_code),by=ID][
    ,multiple_products:=ifelse(max(multiple_products)>1,1,0),by=ID]
    
d
```

**output;**

```
  ID    product_code multiple_products
  <chr> <chr>                    <int>
1 a     B78                          1
2 a     X31                          1
3 b     C12                          0
4 b     C12                          0
```

Comment: Code-golf: remove `ifelse` and use `+(max(multiple_products)>1)`. If you don't like that, then since you're using `data.table` you might as well use its `fifelse`, since `base::ifelse` can be a liability.

Comment: @r2evans can you say more about `ifelse` being a liability? Is it more than that it doesn't check the types it returns?

Comment: @camille it's two things that I know of: (1) not type safe, as you said; and (2) it unclasses things like `POSIXt` and `Date`, despite being numeric-like vectors. Perhaps my labeling it a "liability" sounds harsh, but defensive use of it programmatically now requires preemptive checks and possibly repairs.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
  d,
  multiple_products = +(ave(match(product_code, unique(product_code)), ID, FUN = var) > 0
  )
)
```

gives

```
  ID product_code multiple_products
1  a          B78                 1
2  a          X31                 1
3  b          C12                 0
4  b          C12                 0
```

Comment: For the record this worked without errors on my real dataset, which is very large, while the dplyr-based answer below ran into memory trouble. Not sure why that is but I always appreciate a base `R` option. Cheers.